# How to get beyond DocPad ToS?

Tags: docpad

`docpad run` doesn't behave as indicated on https://docpad.org/docs/install and https://docpad.org/docs/start
It keeps asking me to agree to ToS and it doesn't create any files or run a server.

```
$ docpad run
info: Welcome to DocPad v6.70.1 (global installation: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad)
notice: If everyone who saw this message donated $1/week, maintaining DocPad would become sustainable: http://docpad.org/donate
info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
info: Plugins:
info: Environment: development
Before we continue, have you read and agree to DocPad's Terms of Service (http://bevry.me/tos) and Privacy Policy (http://bevry.me/privacy)? [Y/n] Y
Fantastic. We like informed people!
$ docpad run
info: Welcome to DocPad v6.70.1 (global installation: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad)
notice: If everyone who saw this message donated $1/week, maintaining DocPad would become sustainable: http://docpad.org/donate
info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
info: Plugins:
info: Environment: development
Before we continue, have you read and agree to DocPad's Terms of Service (http://bevry.me/tos) and Privacy Policy (http://bevry.me/privacy)? [Y/n] Y
Fantastic. We like informed people!
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 guaka  staff   68 Feb 13 03:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 guaka  staff  102 Feb 13 03:04 ..
$
```

I gets a bit boring to keep on accepting the ToS, how can I get started building websites?

(Also posted this [in the DocPad issue queue](https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/917) but not much happening there.)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not behind a proxy the [proxy workaround](https://github.com/docpad/docpad/issues/488) suggested here worked for me:

Agree to the TOS manually by filling in your `~/.docpad.cson` or `~/Dropbox/.docpad.cson` (if you have Dropbox installed) file yourself:

```
{
  name: "Your name"
  email: "Your email"
  username: "Your username"
  subscribed: true
  subscribeTryAgain: null
  tos: true
  identified: true
}
```